# List all donations made, by both individual alumni and business donors. Name, ID of the donor, date and amount of the donation must be displayed

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help in this problem. I have the following tables but i cannot seem to get any data out based on the description and query as below.

- **Corporate**(CorporateID(PK), CorporateName, CorporateAddress)
- **Donation**(DonationID(PK), TypeOfDonations)
- **Alumnus**(AlumnusID(PK), CityPK(FK), AlumnusName, EmailAddress, WorkPhoneNumber, HomePhoneNumber, Address
- **Donation_Made**(CorporateDonationID(PK), DonationID(FK), CorporateID(FK), AlumnusID(FK), DonationAmount, DateOfDonation

  `SELECT Z.DONATIONID, A.ALUMNUSNAME, C.CORPORATENAME, Z.DATEOFDONATION, Z.DONATIONAMOUNT
  FROM ALUMNUS A,
  (SELECT * FROM DONATION D LEFT JOIN DONATION_MADE DM
  ON D.DONATIONID = DM.DONATIONID)Z LEFT JOIN CORPORATE C 
  ON C.CORPORATEID = DM.CORPORATEID AND A.ALUMNUSID=DM.ALUMNUSID AND Z.TYPEOFDONATIONS= 'MONETARY';`

Comment: Please provide sample data, the outcome you get with your query, the problem you have with it, and the desired outcome.

Comment: In particular, we need to know how `CorporateID` and `AlumnusID` in `Donation_Made` relate to each other.  Are they 1) always both filled-in? or 2) Always only one filled-in? Or 3) either or both may be filled in, for any one row in `Donation_Made`?

Comment: Hi Barry, it is not required for them to be filled in.

Comment: @Alan, is there a reason why you are not more specific? Could they both be blank? What is the rule? Can you please pick the option that is applicable in the list of RBarryYoung?

Comment: Will you provide sample data and desired outcome?

Comment: Is there an Oracle exam going on somewhere in the world? Are these people simply cheating? It's the third question this morning with a very similar setup, from a third different poster. Is this allowed by the SO rules?

Comment: mathguy bro.. ppl are just asking for help and suggestions here.. it doesnt mean we are cheating.. we tried and we cant seem to get things done and thats why we pop the question.. not everyone is an expert like you.. you see.. if this platform arent meant to ask question then what the point of its existence? ppl sign up in order to get some help and even provide help if they can.. isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use outer join to get data from both Corporate and Alumnus tables.

```
select a.AlumnusID, a.AlumnusName, c.CorporateID, c.CorporateName, dm.DateOfDonation, dm.DonationAmount
from Donation_Made dm 
left outer join on Alumnus a on dm.AlumnusID = a.AlumnusID
left outer join on Corporate c on dm.CorporateID = c.CorporateID
inner join on Donation d on dm.DonationID = d.DonationID
where d.TypeOfDonations='MONETARY';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the fact table, i.e. DONATION_MADE, and then (outer) join the related tables:

```
SELECT     DM.DONATIONID,
           A.ALUMNUSNAME,
           C.CORPORATENAME,
           DM.DATEOFDONATION,
           DM.DONATIONAMOUNT
FROM       DONATION_MADE DM 
INNER JOIN DONATION D
        ON D.DONATIONID = DM.DONATIONID
LEFT JOIN  ALUMNUS A,
        ON A.ALUMNUSID = DM.ALUMNUSID
LEFT JOIN  CORPORATE C
        ON C.CORPORATEID = DM.CORPORATEID
WHERE      D.TYPEOFDONATIONS = 'MONETARY';
```